# Isometries of hyperbolic space

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation, isometry

The [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) for the [Poincaré ball model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) of [hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) is

$$ g_{ij} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{(1 - \lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert^2)^2} $$

where $\mathbf{r}$ is the position in the ambient Euclidean space.

An example of a [uniform tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane) of a 2-dimensional hyperbolic space is shown below:

[image]

My question is as follows:

Given that we use $\mathbf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert^2 < 1$ to model an $n$-dimensional hyperbolic space, what are the isometries of this space in terms of $\mathbf{r}$? How do I express the analogues of translation and rotation in terms of transformations on $\mathbf{r}$ (i.e. rearranging the points in the image above to show a translation or rotation of the entire hyperbolic space)?

So far I have seen examples involving [Mobius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), but how can these be generalized beyond the plane? Is there a general matrix acting on $\mathbf{r}$ that can express these transformations? I may not be understanding this clearly, so please correct me where necessary.

[This paper](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~bowman/metrics.pdf) states that any hyperbolic isometry is induced by a matrix of one of the following types:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
e^t & 0 \\
0 & e^{-t}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \pm 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}
\right)
$$

for geodesic translation by hyperbolic distance $2t$, horocylic translation, and rotation by angle $2 \theta$.

**Edit**

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Isometric_Transformations), if hyperbolic space is translated such that the origin in the unit Poincaré disk is translated to $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{x}$ is translated to

$$\frac{ ( 1 + 2 \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{x} + \left| \mathbf{x} \right| ^2 ) \mathbf{v} + ( 1 - \left| \mathbf{v} \right| ^2 ) \mathbf{x}}{ 1 + 2 \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{x} + \left| \mathbf{v} \right| ^2 \left| \mathbf{x} \right| ^2 }$$

Comment: The Wikipedia article that you linked to states the form of [isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Isometric_Transformations). Nothing new: rotation around the center, inversion in a sphere orthogonal to the given one; and compositions of these things.

Comment: @NormalHuman Are inversions the hyperbolic "reflections"?

Comment: Yes. They are involutions fixing a sphere of hyperplane.